# Cloning an svg group

Tags: svg, clone

I have an svg group which contains some elements, I want to clone the group, problem is the function clones only one element of the group.
Here is the function

```
 <script type="text/ecmascript"><![CDATA[
    function clone(evt) {
        var cloneElement = evt.target.cloneNode(false);
        var newx = 100;
        var newy = 500;
        cloneElement.setAttributeNS(null,"x",newx);
        cloneElement.setAttributeNS(null,"y",newy);
        document.getElementById("layer1").appendChild(cloneElement);
    }

]]></script>
```

The svg looks something like

```
<g id="layer1" onclick="clone(evt)">
<rect>
<path>
<circle>
<circle>
</g>
```

The rectangle is like a container and what happens is that the function clones the rectangle and leaves the other elements.
So what is wrong?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Two things:

- `cloneNode` should be passed true if you want a deeply cloned tree, otherwise it will just clone one element
- `evt.target` will always be the element where the event originated, and g elements are never hit directly, the mouse events just bubble up to there from the children. You can use `evt.currentTarget` instead if you want the element which is currently handling the event (in your case that would be the g element).

Comment: it worked! but the coordinates of the cloned object didn't change to the new ones so i guess i am doing it wrong...

Comment: the g element doesn't have 'x' and 'y' attributes according to the svg spec, but you can use transform="translate(x,y)" instead.